# Scroll page to previous position with a delay when refreshing the page regularly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have tried using the code below to force a regular page refresh and scroll the page to the previous position after however it doesn't seem to work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.reload()
  }, 120000);
})
```

I suspect this is due to the fact that I am using a page loader before my PHP generated table is fully loaded therefore the page isn't the same length when it first loads.

Page loader:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#loader-wrapper').hide();
      $('#tabcontents').fadeIn(500).show();
    }, 700);
  });
```

How can I store the position of the window the user is currently at, refresh the page and then scroll to the same position again after the loader animation finishes and the contents are fully loaded?

Comment: Can you expand on what you're doing?

Comment: @KishanPatel I am using PHP to grab data from a google spreadsheet and then I use javascript to re-arrange the data. I have a simple loader animation to make sure all of the data is re-arranged before the table becomes visible to the user. Because the data comes from a google spreadsheet I need the page to refresh periodically (eg 2mins) in case new data was added to the spreadsheet, however I don't want the page to load back at the top every refresh.

Comment: Instead of reloading the page to reload the data, I would suggest reloading the data using AJAX and replacing the content in the page using jQuery.   So something like `$('#tabcontents').html(<your latest data>)`.  Then the page won't necessarily scroll, or at the very least, you can save your scroll position and re-scroll to that point once the UI has been updated...  I would have to see how you're manipulating the data with javascript, but you could probably do all that in the background, and then put up a temporary indicator that the data was just updated after you replace the table content